# Command Line Windows: How can I set a global variable within a call?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, environment-variables

I want to change a counter variable within a call function.

In my example I want to count all subfolders (= count_all) and afterwards I want to increment the count of the subfolders it successfully proceeded (= count_done).

```
    @echo off
    cls

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set /a "count_all=0"
    set /a "count_done=0"

    for /d /r %%i in (.\*) do call :process_subfolders "%%i"

    if %count_all% EQU 0 (
        echo No archives found.
    ) else (
        set /a "counted=1"
        for /d /r %%i in (.\*) do call :process_subfolders "%%i"
    )

    pause
    endlocal
    goto :eof

    ::___________________________________________________________________
    :process_subfolders
    set "folder=%~nx1"

    pushd %folder%
    if exist *.rar (
        if !counted! equ 0 (
            set /a "count_all+=1"
        ) else (
            set /a "count_done+=1"
            echo !count_done!: %folder%

            rem ... do something with the rar files in this folder ...
            rem ... for testing: use ping
            ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul

            set /a "percent=!count_done!*100/!count_all!"
            title !percent!%% [!count_done!/!count_all!]
        )
    )
    popd
    exit /b
```

The code works but I do not understand the behaviour of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. When I put it in the call `:process_subfolders` I am not able to change the variables anymore and I do not know how to return them accordingly. Somehow I could set them on the end of the call by `endlocal & set "%2=whatever"` (or something like this) but I still do not understand which variables are local and which are not.

What is the difference between `count_all`, `%count_all%` and `!count_all!` and when should I use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the
[FOR /D command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html).

A small test example :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count_all=0
for /d /r %%i in (.\*) do (
  echo !count_all! : %%i
  set /a count_all+=1
)  
echo all: %count_all%
```

As for the difference between the various variable substitution operators,
you are not the only one that is confused here.

The main difference is whether the substitution operator, `%` or `!`,
relates to the current or initial value of the variable.

The
[EnableDelayedExpansion option](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
causes variables to be expanded at execution rather than at parse time.
When delayed expansion is in effect, variables can be immediately read
using `!variable_name!`.
Using `%variable_name%` will continue to show the initial value that is
expanded at the beginning of the line, which may be different for loops.

I have added to my code an `echo` command that demonstrates the difference.
It uses `!count_all!`, because using `%count_all%` would result in the
value as when the `for` command was started, which is always `0`.
But `%%i` does not need the `!` operator, because it is programmed-in
as the loop variable.

You will find a detailed explanation in the following post
(most upvoted answer):
[How do SETLOCAL and ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/how-do-setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-work)

This inconsistency of the two substitution operators leads to confusion
that is not always resolved by logic alone. Sometimes trial and error
is required before getting it right.

Comment: Thanks, that spares the comparison of the paths.

Comment: Sorry but this does not solve the core question :) I've updated my question and the code accordingly.

Comment: I have added more explanations. If you still have questions, please break up your code into small fragments that can better demonstrate the point.

Comment: Thanks again, @harrymc. According to [ss64: EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) the `:subcall` does not need to have the `EnableDelayedExpansion`: _An alternative way to write this is by calling a subroutine, because this breaks out of the loop it does not need Delayed Expansion_